# Setting terminal to raw mode: Character is displayed only after next key pressed

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssh

I'm following the tutorial http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_shell.html on how to program a basic SSH client.

I don't want ENTER key echoed in (local) terminal as a newline. Also, I want input to be read and send as soon as it is ready and not after ENTER has been pressed.

Using the code below, I try to accomplish this.

The problem is, however, that in the client terminal, whenever a key is pressed, the character is first displayed after the next key press. What can be the cause of this behavior?

This function determines whether a key has been pressed:

```
int kbhit()
{
    struct timeval tv = {0L, 0L};
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    return select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
}
```

Read/send data from/to server:

```
struct termios term_attr;
struct termios old_attr;

tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_attr);
cfmakeraw(&term_attr);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term_attr);

while (ssh_channel_is_open(channel) && !ssh_channel_is_eof(channel))
{
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read_nonblocking(channel, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);

    if (nbytes < 0)
    {
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    if (nbytes > 0)
    {
        nwritten = write(1, buff, nbytes);

        if (nwritten != nbytes)
        {
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
    }

    if (!kbhit)
    {
        usleep(5000L);
        continue;
    }

    nbytes = read(0, buff, sizeof(buff));

    if (nbytes < 0)
    {
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }

    if (nbytes > 0)
    {
        nwritten = ssh_channel_write(channel, buff, nbytes);

        if (nwritten != nbytes)
        {
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
    }
}

tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program spends all its time blocked in the `read` function. So it never gets around to calling `ssh_channel_read_nonblocking` until after a key is hit.

Here's the flow:

1. I hit a key.
2. You send that key to the other side.
3. Since `if (!kbhit)` is true (because `kbhit` is not NULL), we go down to `read`.
4. The other side sends us the echo on the ssh channel, but we won't read it because we're blocked in `read` on stdin.
5. You hit the next key, we loop, and call `ssh_channel_read_nonblocking`, get the echo, and echo it.

Perhaps you should call the `kbhit` function rather than testing if the function pointer is false.